# How I can close XNA application before the Form? C#

Tags: c#, xna

I'm doing XNA application. I use Game1.cs (XNA file) and MainForm.cs (form file)

Program.cs

```
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
mainForm.Show();

Game1 game = new Game1(mainForm);
game.Run();
```

When "X" button is clicked I try to close all application in MainForm.cs

```
private void MainForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Unfortunally, Game1.cs is working all time.

I also try to add void Quit() in Game1.cs and active its when X is clicked.

```
public void Quit()
{
    this.Exit();
}
```

How can I close Game1 by pressing X Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your X button handler call:

```
Application.Exit();
this.Exit();
```

The reason being was that `MainForm_FormClosed` was not called due to the form not closing due to a close window not being posted to it.  `Application.Exit()` will do that